# how to read jquery data with python?

Tags: jquery, python, pyquery

I have a big jQuery data with the following format.

```
jQuery({locations: [,…], markersContent: [,…], sidebarContent: [,…]});
```

Is there a way to get the context of first part (locations) with python?
I tried unsuccessfully different commands in **PyQuery**. Can anyone 
suggest a solution?

thanks

Comment: What's a "jQuery data"? jQuery isn't a data format, it's a Javascript library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through your JSON object. or if you have just single JSON inside it access it like

> YOUR_VARIABLE['locations'].

If you have more then one json object inside your variable, you can iterate it like,

```
for key, value in YOUR_VARIABLE.items():
    print(key,value)
```

In that way, you can access your keys and values. Now if you have list inside value, you can iterate through that as well to extract those values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is unclear to me. I wrote this code :
d = pq(url)  print d('locations') ,but it does not work.The problem is how to extract the JSON object!

Comment: Can you put your actual json variable and data here?

Comment: URL = 'http://forms.polycom.com/php/st3/map_data.php?lat=48.1351253&lng=11.581980599999952&categoryid=&page_number=1&nb_display=10&radiusSelect=20&name=&city=Munich&country=Germany&state=&ptlevel=&milesKms=miles&industry=&jsonp_callback=jQuery111207484566748373911_1490620623208&_=1490620623210'